# eConnect XML file detail for GLTransaction using arrays in Dynamics GP

Tags: dynamics-gp, econnect

I am looking to enter a single gltransaction in Dynamics GP using econnect.

My code below does generate an XML file.  However, it places three identical GL line items for $25 dollars each in the XML file leaving an unbalanced entry.

What I would like it to do instead is place a $75 debit, a $50 credit and a $25 credit per the code below.  Can you help me troubleshoot what I have done wrong specifically so that I do not have three $25 items coming into the file?

Thanks in advance.

```
string DTime = DateTime.Today.ToString();
string CurrentDatabase = "OCITE";
string NextJEno = GetNextJournal.GetNextJournalEntry(CurrentDatabase);

eConnectType eConnect = new eConnectType();

GLTransactionType myGLTrxType = new GLTransactionType();
taGLTransactionHeaderInsert myGLHeader = new taGLTransactionHeaderInsert();
taGLTransactionLineInsert_ItemsTaGLTransactionLineInsert [] myGLDetail = new taGLTransactionLineInsert_ItemsTaGLTransactionLineInsert[3];
taGLTransactionLineInsert_ItemsTaGLTransactionLineInsert myGLDetailLine = new taGLTransactionLineInsert_ItemsTaGLTransactionLineInsert();

myGLDetailLine.BACHNUMB = CurrentDatabase;
myGLDetailLine.JRNENTRY = Int32.Parse(NextJEno);
myGLDetailLine.CRDTAMNT = (decimal)0;
myGLDetailLine.DEBITAMT = (decimal)75.00;
myGLDetailLine.ACTNUMST = "1000-0000-C";

myGLDetail[0] = myGLDetailLine;

myGLDetailLine.BACHNUMB = CurrentDatabase;
myGLDetailLine.JRNENTRY = Int32.Parse(NextJEno);
myGLDetailLine.CRDTAMNT = (decimal)50;
myGLDetailLine.DEBITAMT = (decimal)0;
myGLDetailLine.ACTNUMST = "6560-0000-C";

myGLDetail[1] = myGLDetailLine;

myGLDetailLine.BACHNUMB = CurrentDatabase;
myGLDetailLine.JRNENTRY = Int32.Parse(NextJEno);
myGLDetailLine.CRDTAMNT = (decimal)25;
myGLDetailLine.DEBITAMT = (decimal)0;
myGLDetailLine.ACTNUMST = "5120-0000-C";

myGLDetail[2] = myGLDetailLine;

myGLHeader.BACHNUMB = CurrentDatabase; 
myGLHeader.JRNENTRY = Int32.Parse(NextJEno);
myGLHeader.REFRENCE = "REFRENCE";
myGLHeader.TRXDATE = DTime;
myGLHeader.TRXTYPE = 0;

myGLTrxType.taGLTransactionLineInsert_Items = myGLDetail;
myGLTrxType.taGLTransactionHeaderInsert = myGLHeader;
GLTransactionType[] myGLType = { myGLTrxType };
eConnect.GLTransactionType = myGLType;

FileStream streamFile = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);
XmlTextWriter Xmlwriter = new XmlTextWriter(streamFile, new UTF8Encoding());

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(eConnect.GetType());
serializer.Serialize(Xmlwriter, eConnect);
Xmlwriter.Close();
```

XML file

```
<eConnect xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<GLTransactionType>
<eConnectProcessInfo xsi:nil="true" />
<taRequesterTrxDisabler_Items xsi:nil="true" />
<taGLTransactionLineInsert_Items>
<taGLTransactionLineInsert>
<BACHNUMB>OCITE</BACHNUMB>
<JRNENTRY>1750</JRNENTRY>
<CRDTAMNT>25</CRDTAMNT>
<DEBITAMT>0</DEBITAMT>
<ACTNUMST>5120-0000-C</ACTNUMST>
</taGLTransactionLineInsert>
<taGLTransactionLineInsert>
<BACHNUMB>OCITE</BACHNUMB>
<JRNENTRY>1750</JRNENTRY>
<CRDTAMNT>25</CRDTAMNT>
<DEBITAMT>0</DEBITAMT>
<ACTNUMST>5120-0000-C</ACTNUMST>
</taGLTransactionLineInsert>
<taGLTransactionLineInsert>
<BACHNUMB>OCITE</BACHNUMB>
<JRNENTRY>1750</JRNENTRY>
<CRDTAMNT>25</CRDTAMNT>
<DEBITAMT>0</DEBITAMT>
<ACTNUMST>5120-0000-C</ACTNUMST>
</taGLTransactionLineInsert>
</taGLTransactionLineInsert_Items>
<taAnalyticsDistribution_Items xsi:nil="true" />
<taGLTransactionHeaderInsert>
<BACHNUMB>OCITE</BACHNUMB>
<JRNENTRY>1750</JRNENTRY>
<REFRENCE>REFRENCE</REFRENCE>
<TRXDATE>3/21/2013 12:00:00 AM</TRXDATE>
<TRXTYPE>0</TRXTYPE>
</taGLTransactionHeaderInsert>
<taMdaUpdate_Items xsi:nil="true" />
</GLTransactionType>
</eConnect>
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution to my own question.

Namely, creating a new instance of the myGLDetailLine object for 'every' single line will resolve this problem.

```
taGLTransactionLineInsert_ItemsTaGLTransactionLineInsert myGLDetailLine = new taGLTransactionLineInsert_ItemsTaGLTransactionLineInsert();
```